# increase exectution speed php scripts on localhost of xampp

Tags: php, mysql, performance, xampp, localhost

I have to extract words from a lot of text files and check if they exist in this large wordnet database in phpmyadmin. Because of the looping and checking(mysql) it takes 3 to 4 minutes for executing.

Is there any way to optimize? Would increasing db buffer size help,;if yes then how to do that?

Comment: Are you executing one mySQL query for each word? How large is the mySQL wordnet database?

Comment: yes,entire databse is 40 mb,the table i use are 4 and 11mb.Do you think i will make a difference if i make a seperate databse for the tables i use only??..i extract all the words from the text into an array,them i check i they exist in the wordnet word table if they do i get their wordid and from this i get the words definition,is there any other better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

just load the words all at once into php memory as a hashmap. like

```
$words = array(
    'foo' => 1, 'bar' => 1, 'baz' => 1
);

//then check like
$exists = isset($words[ $word ]);
```

Comment: thanks for the help,but i think its the sql queries which are slowing the process down,because initially i read the entire files and displayed their words at once using basic arrays, this process however didnt take that much time.its only now that when i check for the existence of the words in the database the execution time exceeds the limit

Comment: yes exactly. that's why my suggestion eliminates the database. You must misunderstand. Get the words from the database with one query, put them into an array, *then* read the files and check for existence.

Comment: there are 147,305 records wont it be slow if i get all those records?

Comment: thnx!! you were right my execution time halved though it didnt take exactly 2min i had to change my code structure a bit

Answer (score 0):

you could cache an index of all the words in memory in a tree structure and store a pointer to the record with offsets of where the words are found. You could use a [Binary Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) or a custom tree that has nodes with a possible 26 pointers to get to the next letter.

Answer (score 0):

I had once this issue when searching and sorting a database with 16 million rows of university result data (Indian Universities are large :) ). We had experienced fantastic improvement using `MyISAM` instead of `InnoDB` and keeping Indexes on fields exactly in the ***same sequence*** as in the `where` clause.

This will make MySQL fast but to make PHP fast we only found Intel Xeon fit for the purpose. For the test environment we had installed a virtual server on a multi-cpu quad core Xeon server with abundant RAM (16GB was abundant 4 yrs ago). We ran the PHP script in there with the MySQL server residing on another server nearby and had exceptionally fast results. FYI, we didnt have any threading or special code but our normal script just ran at awesome speed in that environment when our high end desktops and laptops with desktop processors seemed to take ages to run that same script!

No idea if this will help you but just wanted to share my experience!